# Python - Get Value from List in Dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am working on some software to use across multiple computers, and has an FTP server that will be created using the library `pyftpdlib` to use for downloading needed files from the "manager". While I am setting up the authorization for it, I ran across the issue of how to get a value from a list, in my `param` dictionary, that is filled from a file named `config.json`. Here is my code below for if the file does not exist:

```
if not os.path.exists("config.json"):
    name = socket.gethostname()
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(name)
    params['ip'] = []
    params['ftp_creds'] = []
    params['output_directory'] = []
    params['ip'].append({
        'address': str(ip)
    })
    params['ftp_creds'].append({
        'username': 'root',
        'password': '12345',
        'directory': 'ftp_files'
    })
    params['output_directory'].append({
        'output-directory': 'render_out'
    })
    with open("config.json","w") as file:
        json.dump(params, file)
    print("File config.json did not exist, wrote it. Please restart script.")
    sys.exit()
```

Down further in the script, I have a couple lines of code setting up the "authorizer" that are a work in progress.

```
ftp_authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
ftp_authorizer.add_user(perm="elradfmwMT")
```

The `perm="elradfmwMT"` argument will not be the only argument, as I will be getting values from the dictionary to set up username, password, etc.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the value from `params['ftp_creds]` what you have done is appended a dictionary to the list. `params['ftp_creds'][0]` is a dictionary from which you can access the password via `params['ftp_creds'][0]['password']`.